# what is difference between an in-memory database and disk database that uses cache? (based on NoSQL)

Tags: database, nosql, in-memory-database

1.
It's clear that memory is faster than disk.
But it's just the difference between memory and disk.
What is the difference between In-memory NoSQL and using (memory)cache disk NoSQL?

2.
what is Hybrid NoSQL? it is same the NewSQL?
Can you explain exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The differences between an IMDS and a persistent DBMS are unrelated to SQL/NewSQL or any name you want to give SQL. We (McObject, my employer) wrote a white paper on the differences. It's vendor-neutral. You can access it free (no registration needed) here: https://www.mcobject.com/embedded-database-white-papers/ Look for "In Memory Database Systems: Myths and Facts".

Also, this: https://www.mcobject.com/february10-2010/